# How to prevent the BreezeJS MetaData call being made multiple times

Tags: breeze

I am using BreezeJS with Angular2 and have noticed that the MetaData call is called multiple times.

I have tried to prime the cache by calling fetchMetadata() on the constructor of my BreezeDataService, however this has made no difference (it adds yet another metadata call).

```
this.entityManager.fetchMetadata().then(function () { console.log('entityManager.fetchMetadata finished'); });
```

I assume it is caused by 5 requests for data being made when the home page loads and each one goes off to fetch the metadata without waiting for the existing metadata call to complete.

You can see the problem on [www.quemesa.com](http://www.quemesa.com) with the NetWorks tools:[image]  (The first 5 are the PReflight CORS requests)

How can I tell the code to wait for any existing metadata call to complete instead of fetching it again?

**UPDATE WITH CODE:**

```
@Injectable()
export class DataBreezeService {
    public isSaving: boolean = false;
    public entityManager: EntityManager;

    constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService, private loggerService: LoggerService) {  
        this.entityManager = new EntityManager(environment.webApiServiceUrl);
        this.entityManager.metadataStore.namingConvention = NamingConvention.camelCase;

        this.entityManager.fetchMetadata().then(() => this.loggerService.info('entityManager.fetchMetadata finished'));
    }

    public executeQueryArray(query: EntityQuery) {
        return this.entityManager.executeQuery(query)
            .then((queryResult: QueryResult) => this.successArrayDataLoad(queryResult))
            .catch((error) => this.errorDataLoad(error))    
    }
```

and then I have different Entity Services that use the DataBreezeService :

```
@Injectable()
export class BookingService {
    constructor(private dataBreezeService: DataBreezeService, private loggerService: LoggerService) {
    }

    public getBookingsForUser(userId: number, forceServerCall: boolean = false) {
        this.dataBreezeService.initialiseQuery('getBookingsForUser', [userId], forceServerCall);

        let query = new EntityQuery()
            .from("bookings")
            .where("createdByUserId", "==", userId)
            .where("visibilityId", "==", Status.Active)  //booking is active
            .toType('Booking')
            .expand('createdByUser, restaurant, restaurant.suburb, restaurantScheduleDiscount, rating')
            .orderBy("bookingDate Desc")
            .inlineCount();  //return total

        return this.dataBreezeService.executeQueryArray(query);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My team and I came up with a solution for this problem.  I will do my best to explain how we did it.  Our changes involved customizations to breeze.debug.js.  This is important!  Since this involves changes to Breeze.js, be prepared to make the changes again if you upgrade to a new version of Breeze.js!

IndexedDB is more challenging than using localStorage, we do it because we run Breeze in a webworker - and Local Storage is not available inside web workers.  Only IndexedDB is.

1) We check an indexedDB database for the metadata in proto.fetchMetadata.  If it's not found (or indexedDB is not supported), the method falls back to default behavior.

2) If IndexedDB is supported, in the success promise of the Ajax call in proto.ajaxMetaData, we write metadata to an IndexedDB database.

Consider carefully how long you want to persist the metadata cache in IndexedDB.  Is it each session?  Each new build (which might contain new metadata)?  You might want to create a script that periodically deletes your metadata cache.  We have code that returns DLL version information of the website DLL's - which we compare to a local storage key to determine if we have a new build.   This is the least restrictive policy... it only clears the cache if a new build is running.

However, you might want to clear the cache each time the user creates a new session.  Either way, the key you use for each IndexedDB entry should be unique - containing the route, the data context (and optionally the sessionid if that kind of reset is important.)

You can use very long strings as keys.  I recommend creating a javascript object that contains all the unique parts of the key (route, dllVersion, UserId), then converting the object to a JSON string - and using that string as the IndexedDB key.

Even if you don't apply caching of your metadata, you should at least broadcast an event when the metadata for your request has loaded, like this:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('MetaDataLoaded' + serviceRoute, dataContext);
```

We have a wrapper class which broadcasts this event when the metadata is completely loaded.  If you don't use a wrapper, you would probably want to put the broadcast in proto.ajaxMetaData, or if you implement caching, broadcast it right before you return the metadata from your IndexedDB cache.

In your calling controller, use this to listen for that event:

```
$scope.$on('MetaDataLoadedServiceRoute', function (event, args) {
     $scope.setup();
});
```

This allows you to wait until you have metadata before making your first request in the controller.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you really saying that the same `EntityManager` instance issues more than one metadata request? I don't remember that being the case.

If it truly is, (a) we should fix that - file an issue - and (b) you can workaround it in your data service.

You DO have a data service, right? Your components should never talk to the EM directly but rather through an intermediate service that insulates the components from direct contact with the manager and abstracts that interaction into something semantic. You'll see that advice *everywhere* for Angular apps, whether using Breeze or not.

Assuming you're following that advice, you can fetch metadata in an initialization step, hold onto the promise, and chain all subsequent calls through that resolved promise.

Probably simpler to have an initialization step in your app that leverages that metadata promise AND any other priming activity that pre-loads the cache.

You can also pre-cache the metadata on the server and load it as JSON-ish via a JavaScript tag. Examples of that are in the Breeze docs.

So lots of options for you.

Last thought. How many `EntityManager`s are you creating? By default, each will fetch metadata. Most folks only need one but there are reasons to want more. If you need more, make sure you designate one as the "master" and use the copy constructor to create the others.

Comment: Hi Ward, yes, I did use data services -I have added some more code. I think the part that is not working (and that I am not understanding) is this suggestion "Assuming you're following that advice, you can fetch metadata in an initialization step, hold onto the promise, and chain all subsequent calls through that resolved promise."  In the DataBreezeService I declare an entityManager: EntityManager - how do I tell all calls that use it to WAIT until the first MetaData call has finished?